# Change of 'QuerySet' from Django 1.4 to 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.7, django-1.4

I'm trying to port an app from Django 1.4.15 -> 1.7.3

I've come to a problem where the app have a method in models.py

```
def is_votable(self, user):
        '''
        Decides if the user can vote for him/herself or not
        '''
        if self.rated_by.all().__contains__(user):
            return False
        return True
```

the problem I have is located on this line:

```
if self.rated_by.all().__contains__(user):
```

Which creates the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

I'm probably blind as I can't see where `__contains__` get deprecated in Django.
Any help is deeply appreciated. Also just ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should almost never be calling double-underscore methods like `__contains__` in your code. In almost all circumstances, you use the `in` operator:

```
if user in self.rated_by.all():
```

Note that this is a Python-wide thing: eg instead of calling `mylist.__length__()` you would do `len(mylist)`, instead of doing `myobj.__unicode__()` you do `unicode(myobj)`, etc.

In this particular circumstance, though, you might also find it more efficient to do a query:

```
if self.rated_by.filter(user_id=user.id).exists():
```

This hits the database for a single EXISTS query. If you're not using the `rated_by` queryset anywhere else on that particular object, this will definitely be more efficient than querying `all()` and checking membership.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Also explains a lot. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, to indicate to future searchers that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `__contains__` method was [removed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/70679243d1786e03557c28929f9762a119e3ac14#diff-5b0dda5eb9a242c15879dc9cd2121379L145) when queryset iteration was [changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.6/#queryset-iteration) to no longer create the models in chunks.

While `in` calls the `__contains__` method if it exists, it doesn't need to exist for the `in` operator to work. In fact it works if you provide just an `__iter__` method that returns an iterable. As the refactoring no longer needed any special logic, and `__contains__` was a private function, it was removed without any specific notes in the release notes. That's a good reason to do what Daniel suggested and always use the public API, i.e. the `in` operator.